Can't find the correct artifacts
I have a pipeline (MainPipeline) which triggers another one (DependantPipeline).
However my DependantPipeline can't read it, I suppose my mistake somewhere in one of the pipeline definitions.
The prepare.yml which might be useful here. I modified it a bit, this is how it looks like currently:
parameters:
  - name: pipelineOptions
    type: object
  - name: env
    type: string
  - name: region
    type: string
    default: $(region)
  - name: artifactStagingDirectory
    type: string
  - name: artifactName
    type: string
    default: terraform_src

steps:
  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    displayName: "Download Terraform Sources"
    inputs:
      source: 'specific'
      project: $(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.projectName)
      pipeline: $(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.pipelineName)
      artifact: ${{parameters.artifactName}}
      runVersion: 'specific'
      runId: $(resources.pipeline.SourcePipeline.runID)
      path: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/DetectChanges'
[...]

It leads to the error saying that cant find the proper file.
Would someone resolve me that issue? I can provide more yml definitions if needed.

I'm afraid we don't have enough information to understand where the problem is. Please show us the job(s) where the artifacts are being downloaded and used.

Sure, give me a while, and thanks for the quick reply.

It seems you're not downloading the artifacts that contains the terraform code - that's why you see errors like Given variables file xxxx.tfvars does not exist.
For example, the following task will disable artifacts download:
  steps:
    - download: none

Also, in prepare.yml the task DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 is commented out.
Finally, please note that setting buildType: 'current' in DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 means that the task will try to download artifacts produced by the current pipeline.
See Download artifacts from a specific project/pipeline or Download an artifact from a specific build run.

I changed all above steps. Now, it fails in different step, Configure Terraform Global which is part of the prepare.yml. I put the modified version under the EDIT 1 section in the main question.

@Kreg double-check where exactly the artifacts (*.tf files) are being downloaded - for example running ls -R $(Pipeline.Workspace).

I added new bash step and the output in the main article. Really thanks for your very quick replies :)

@Kreg you have a parameter named artifactName but you're hard-coding the path in one of the DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 tasks.
Shouldn't it be $(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{ parameters.artifactName }}' instead of path: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/DetectChanges'?

You were right, now it passes that step. There is another problem with fetching correct docker image (also in Terraform Plan step), can we continue in that question, or better create new one? I would not like to lose context.

@Kreg different problem, different question :-) If my answer helped you solve the artifacts downloading issue please consider accepting it and/or upvoting it.

Clear, just wanted to clarify it.

There could still be other .yml templates including the download or DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 steps that you haven't shared.
If your dependent pipeline was triggered by the pipeline called dev-crunch with the symbolic alias of MainPipeline, you may try to add the sample steps under your steps node in the YAML definition to see if the artifacts published by MainPipeline was downloaded during the dependent pipeline run
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: MainPipeline
      project: DEV
      source: 'dev-crunch'
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - test/pipeline

- download: MainPipeline
  artifact: terraform_src
  displayName: Download artifdacts terraform_src published by MainPipeline with definition name dev-crunch

- script: |
    echo "================ 1. Checking files in Pipeline.Workspace - $(Pipeline.Workspace) ================"
    cd "$(Pipeline.Workspace)"
    tree
    echo "================ 2. Checking files in terraformConfigDirectory - $(terraformConfigDirectory) ================"
    cd "$(terraformConfigDirectory)"
    tree
    echo "================ 3. Checking files in Pipeline.Workspace/parameters.artifactName/terraform ================"
    cd "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{parameters.artifactName}}/terraform"
    tree
  displayName: Check downloaded artifacts files location
  condition: always()

By default, we can locate the download and check steps by their displayName easily in the logs and should be able to see the artifacts files are downloaded into the path of $(Pipeline.Workspace)/<PipelineRsourceSymbolicName>/<ArtifactsName> ie $(Pipeline.Workspace)/MainPipeline/terraform_src in our case. Please also make sure your terraform commands were run in the correct workingDirectory.


In my spare time I will check it. Thank you very much, you are almost always in my question active :) Meanwhile it turns out that I made a mistake in hardcoding one variable, what Rui found.
